# Use CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR, in a function

Tags: cmake

I have a CMakeLists.txt that defines a function, that needs to refer to its own path because it needs to use a file in its own directory:

```
├── path/to/a:
|   ├── CMakeLists.txt
|   └── file_i_need.in
└── different/path/here:
    └── CMakeLists.txt
```

The `path/to/a/CMakeLists.txt` file has a function that needs to `configure_file()`:

```
function(do_something_interesting ...)
    configure_file(
        file_i_need.in  ## <== how do I get the path to this file
        file_out        ## <== this one I don't need to path
        )
endfunction()
```

I can write `path/to/a/file_i_need.in` on that line, but that seems overly cumbersome. I can use `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}` outside of the function, but inside of the function when called by `different/path/here/CMakeLists.txt` it'll be `different/path/here` instead.

Is there a way to refer to the path of *this* CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outside of any function store value of *CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR* into a variable, then use that variable in a function, defined in that file.

Definition of a variable depends on visibility relation between a script, which defines a function (**define-script**) and a script, which could use that function(**use-script**).

1. **use-script** is executed *in the scope* of **define-script**.

   This is most common case, when *use-script* is included into *define-script* or one of its parents.

   The variable can be defined as a simple variable:

   ```
   set(_my_dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
   ```
2. **use-script** is executed *out of the scope* of **define-script**. Note, that a function's definition is *global*, so it is visible anywhere.

   This case corresponds to the code in the question post, where `CMakeLists.txt` files, corresponded to **use-script** and **define-script**, belongs to *different subtrees*.

   The variable can be defined as a *CACHE* variable:

   ```
   set(_my_dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} CACHE INTERNAL "")
   ```

The function definition is the same in both cases:

```
function(do_something_interesting ...)
    configure_file(
        ${_my_dir}/file_i_need.in  ## <== Path to the file in current CMake script
        file_out        ## <== this one I don't need to path
        )
endfunction()
```

In both cases name of variable (`_my_dir`) should be somehow unique. It could include a project's name (for scripts `CMakeLists.txt`) or a script name (for scripts `<name>.cmake`).

Comment: From the other path, `${_my_dir}` shows up as empty (I'm on cmake 3.10 if that matters)

Comment: Yes, I have missed the fact that in your case `path/to/a/CMakeLists.txt` and `different/path/here/CMakeLists.txt` corresponds to *different subtrees*. I have updated the answer with this case (2nd).

Answer (score 3):

Just as an update, since [release CMake 3.17](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.17.html#variables) you can now use `CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR`.
ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR.html

So your sample becomes:

```
function(do_something_interesting ...)
    configure_file(
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR}/file_i_need.in  ## <== Path to the file in current CMake script
        file_out        ## <== this one I don't need to path
        )
endfunction()
```